Find IC used in Microwave motion sensor (701E)
I am working on a project that involves 5.25Ghz microwave motion sensor, to properly get the results i need to integrate the microwave sensor with arduino.
I found a device having the same specs but inside the pcb of device there is a 14 Pin IC used to drive the relay circuit for controlling the light on/off. I am trying to find the datasheet of the IC
on the IC 701E is written I couldnt find any information as regarding the same. The device is made by China-Starlux.
Device link https://techlogics.net/microwave-human-body-motion-detector-load-light-wiring-connection-diagram/





Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I m trying to understand the working of 5.25 ghz microwave motion sensor,  in the Pcb of the device there is a 14 pin IC, which is masked and there is "701 E" written on it.
I am trying to find the datasheet of the IC. In the photo above I have attached is the
pin connections of the IC,  and the link is of the actual Product

I'm afraid the chances that this IC is identifiable are very low. These sparse markings on a big package like SOP14 usually mean that it's some custom ASIC. Even the obscure Chinese MCU manufacturers typically have better markings.
